# PyQt5 data lost during signal emit in bytes type

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 and Python 3 to display some data received from an embedded device through serial port. The library, PySerial, is used to handle the serial communication. Since the return type of the read function from PySerial is `bytes`, I use a thread to emit the received data in `bytes` type. Interestingly, the byte `b'\x00'` and all the bytes afterwards are lost during the emit-receive cycle. However, if the type of the emit signal is set to be `QByteArray`, the data is correctly emitted and received.

Below is a MWE to reproduce the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Example(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    new_bytes = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bytes)
    new_qba = QtCore.pyqtSignal('QByteArray')
    bytes_to_emit = b'\x01\x00\x02'

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.init_ui()
        self.setWindowTitle('Emit Bytes Bug')

    def init_ui(self):
        emit_label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Data to emit')
        data_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.bytes_to_emit.hex())

        emit_bytes_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Emit bytes')
        emit_qba_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Emit QByteArray')
        self.rev_bytes_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.rev_qba_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        clear_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Clear receive')

        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        grid_layout.addWidget(emit_label, 0, 0)
        grid_layout.addWidget(data_label, 0, 1)
        grid_layout.addWidget(emit_bytes_button, 1, 0)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.rev_bytes_edit, 1, 1)
        grid_layout.addWidget(emit_qba_button, 2, 0)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.rev_qba_edit, 2, 1)
        grid_layout.addWidget(clear_button, 3, 0)

        self.setLayout(grid_layout)

        emit_bytes_button.clicked.connect(self.on_bytes_button)
        emit_qba_button.clicked.connect(self.on_qba_button)
        self.new_bytes.connect(self.update_byte_receive)
        self.new_qba.connect(self.update_qba_receive)
        clear_button.clicked.connect(self.on_clear_button)

    def update_byte_receive(self, data):
        data_str = data.hex()
        self.rev_bytes_edit.insert(data_str)

    def update_qba_receive(self, data):
        tmp_bytes = bytes(data)
        data_str = tmp_bytes.hex()
        self.rev_qba_edit.insert(data_str)

    def on_bytes_button(self):
        self.new_bytes.emit(self.bytes_to_emit)

    def on_qba_button(self):
        self.new_qba.emit(self.bytes_to_emit)

    def on_clear_button(self):
        self.rev_bytes_edit.clear()
        self.rev_qba_edit.clear()

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Example()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The data to be emit is `b'\x01\x00\x02'`, click the 'Emit bytes' button will emit the data in 'bytes' type and display the received data in the lineedit on right of the button. Similarly, click the 'Emit QByteArray' button will emit the data in `QByteArray` type and display the received data on the button's corresponding lineedit. The 'Clear receive' button just clears the lineedits.

Though I already know the alternative working solution, i.e. emit the bytes signal using `QByteArray` type, I wonder which signal type is preferred when emmit a signal. Should it be faster using the Python 3's native `bytes` type if the data needs to be emit is already in `bytes` type? Or PyQt5's `QByteArray` is closer to the underlying C++ code? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Python3 version: 3.5

PyQt5 version: 5.7

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm using Python 3.4 and PySide 1.2.2 and this code works perfectly fine.

Comment: @HashSplat this will likely be due to the differences in the way `PyQt` and `PySide` handle type conversions between `python` and `C++`

Comment: @user3419537. Nope. It also works perfectly fine for me using Python-3.6 and PyQt-5.7.1, and there's really no reason why it shouldn't. The type received by `update_byte_receive` is `<class 'bytes'>`, as expected, and the value is not truncated. If the OP gets something different, it must be due to a bug in the specific versions of SIP and/or PyQt5 they are using.

Comment: @user3419537. PyQt5 is only fully tested for Python 3, so all bets are off as far as Python 2 is concerned. If you use a Python `bytearray`, the example should work, though.

Comment: @ekhumoro ah yes, you are quite right. I maintain my own builds of `PyQt` and completely forgot the official releases are Python3 only. And yes, everything works as expected with `bytearray`. My bad for testing with Python 2

Comment: Actually this is the last problem after I migrated my code from Python 2.7 and PyQt4 to Python 3.5 and PyQt5. In my PyQt4 code, I use the `QString` API v2 and emit the signal in `bytes` (imported from builtins). I don't recall there was any data lost.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes, the received type by `update_byte_receive` is `'bytes'` as expected, but with data truncation. Can I have your version of SIP please? I may give it a test using your enviroment.

Comment: @Daniel. Under the skin, PyQt4 and PyQt5 are quite different in some ways. I suggest you try using PyQt-5.7.1. I'm pretty certain there was a bug related to this that was fixed fairly recently. PS: I tested with both SIP-4.19 and SIP-4.19.1.

Comment: @ekhumoro Just upgraded to PyQt5-5.8 and sip-4.19.1 and the problem is solved. So it might be a bug in previous combination of PyQt5-5.7 and sip-4.18.1. Many thanks for the comments:)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the PyQt Documentation for [Signals and Slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#unbound-and-bound-signals)

> When a signal is emitted then any arguments are converted to C++ types if possible.

and [Python Strings, Qt Strings and Unicode](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/gotchas.html#python-strings-qt-strings-and-unicode)

> For Python v3 the following conversions are done by default.
>
> - If `Qt` expects a `char *` (or a `const` version) then `PyQt5` will accept a    `str` that contains only ASCII characters, a `bytes`, a `QByteArray`,
>     or a    Python object that implements the `buffer` protocol.
> - If `Qt` expects a `char` (or a `const` version) then `PyQt5` will accept the    same types as for `char *` and also require that a single
>     character is    provided.
> - If `Qt` expects a `signed char *` or an `unsigned char *` (or a `const`    version) then `PyQt5` will accept a `bytes`.
> - If `Qt` expects a `signed char` or an `unsigned char` (or a `const` version)    then `PyQt5` will accept a `bytes` of length 1.
> - If `Qt` expects a `QString` then `PyQt5` will accept a `str`, a `bytes` that    contains only `ASCII` characters, a `QByteArray` or `None`.
> - If `Qt` expects a `QByteArray` then `PyQt5` will also accept a `bytes`.
> - If `Qt` expects a `QByteArray` then `PyQt5` will also accept a `str` that    contains only `Latin-1` characters.

As you can see, there are several `C++/Qt` types that `PyQt` will happily convert a `bytes` object to. How does it know you want a `QByteArray`? It doesn't.

If you stop your code in a debugger and take a look at the `new_bytes` signal, you will see that the signal has been given the `QString` type (at least this is what happens under python2.7 on my system). If you are familiar with how `C` strings work, you will know that the byte `x/00` indicates the end of the string, regardless of the buffer size. This is why your output terminates after `x/00.

Either way the python object needs to be converted to a `C++` type. Declaring the signal with `QtCore.pyqtSignal('QByteArray')` tells `PyQt` explicitly which type you want.

Comment: Most of this is not really relevant, because in the example the signal is defined and emitted in Python, not Qt/C++. This matters, for instance, when emitting Python-specific objects (e.g. `tuple`) that Qt/C++ knows nothing about. For those cases, no conversion is done at all - effectively, a pointer is emitted instead.  It is also vital that you test using Python 3, not Python 2. For the latter, you will need to use a Python `bytearray` rather than `bytes` to get the correct behaviour.

Comment: Is there any preference between python3's `bytes` and PyQt5's `QByteArray` for the type of signal to emit, provided by the expected data type is `bytes` in both sender and receiver?

Comment: @Daniel. On the face of it, if you're receiving `bytes`, then it would seem more performant to also send `bytes`, since it avoids converting to/from a `QByteArray`. However, the proof of the pudding is in the eating, and you know where the [timeit module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) is, right? My hunch is it will make very little difference unless you're sending large amounts of data, or emitting millions of signals per second, or somesuch.